# How to not show shapes behind object in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

I imported this model from other blender 3 to blender 2.79, but I can't turn off x-ray in edit mode, it wasn't on while i was working on blender 3? Can someone tell me how do I change this?

This is how it looks imported from blender 3
[image]

This is how I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: It's not recommended to open Blender 3 files in previous versions of Blender, especially as far back as 2.79 as there's no guarantee they will be compatible.

Comment: As far as I can remember you need to activate `Limit selection to visible` in the middle of the area header between `Face select` and `Proportional Editing` (icon with two squares).

Comment: @relaxed, its seems that he already has it deactivated tho.

Comment: @MoonMoon can you share the file?